# _.now and Date.now difference

Tags: javascript, lodash

I was scrolling through lodash documentation and found myself confused at `_.now()`. While checking in console: `_.now() === Date.now()` I found out that it's true. So.. I went to their source, but it is such a big code that I am actually even more confused after that. Can anyone explain to me what difference will I get if I use `_.now()`?

Comment: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/67389a8c78975d97505fa15aa79bec6397749807/lodash.js#L9960 its this much only

Comment: It literally just calls `Date.now()`.